# organisation of classes in python, anything possible?

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I am teaching myself python and I am new to object oriented languages at all.
I have been reading books and the internet about this, but I realised that coding is the best practice. I am doing that, but struggling with the following:

Can my programmes be structured in virtually any possible way regarding classes or are there restrictions (e.g. referencing functions and variables back and forth between classes)? Can the programmes theoretically be broken down to Classes in whatever way?
For example: A simple text editor with Tkinter: Can the creation of the menu bar, in which I load the content of a text file, be placed in one class, and have another class with the creation of the text field?

I am struggling because either the text field or the menu bar gets created first, obviously. But content coming from the menu (load file) gets sent/inserted into the text field. So the menu must come first. On the other hand the text comes before saving into a file (in the menu class).

What am I missing?

I am really hoping to get help from you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm sorry, but I think your question is too vague and overly broad to be answered here on SO; see the [FAQ#dontask]. If you have more concrete problems (preferably involving some code), feel free to ask those!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kudos for the thought put into this post. You could structure your program in any of the ways you suggest, it's all a matter of preference.

As to your text editor question, it doesn't matter which class is created first - both can still be there when you need them, and if they're connected correctly then one can pass information to the other.

Trust me, the more you code, the more obvious this will become. Good luck :-D

Answer (score 0):

There are no such restrictions when it comes to structuring your code. However, keep in mind the following:

1. Any object that you want to refer to must be created before you use it.
2. In Python, two of anything of the same name will overwrite each other, and only the latest will be used.
3. Methods are executed when called, not when created.

Here is an example of #2:

```
def foo(bar):
    print(bar)
    return 42
def foo(bar):
    print(bar)
    return 'The answer to the universe'

print foo('The question')
```

In the above snippet, only the second function definition is valid, and it will be executed. This is because methods names are just like any other name in Python. They can be assigned, reassigned, and overwritten.

Later on, you can `foo = 'Python'` and it is perfectly okay.

This will become more evident as you start developing.

Comment: thank you very much for your answers. it was helpful as i now know that i basically cannot make any "mistake" (or create something like a dead end) in structuring. next time I will post code together with a precise question.